# C++ application built with 120_xp toolset on Windows XP: InitializeCriticalSectionEx could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

Tags: c++, windows-xp, visual-studio-2013

I've built my application with 120_XP toolset in VS 2013. When trying to run it on XP, I get an error:

> The procedure entry point InitializeCriticalSectionEx could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

This is a known problem for VS 2012 and was fixed in Update 3. But I'm using VS 2013, and can't find any solutions or even mentions of this issues with 2013. Any ideas?

Comment: That's because VS2013 doesn't have this problem.  Perhaps a DLL you depend on that still links an old copy of msvcr110.dll does.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to find it.

Comment: @HansPassant: You're right, one of my 3rd-party dlls was built with 120, not 120_xp. Please make this an answer :)

Comment: No, that's not the answer.  Such a DLL will fail to load entirely since it asks for the wrong subsystem version.

Comment: @HansPassant: Good catch. Then I still don't get it. Guess I will have to inspect all the dlls to see which one imports `InitializeCriticalSectionEx`.

Comment: @HansPassant: I've inspected my main .exe module and every single non-Windows .dll that the .exe depends on with DependencyWalker. None of them imports `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` from kernel32.dll. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Right, that's the way it should be.  Msvcr120.dll and the *later* updates for msvcr110.dll use GetProcAddress() to find the function so they can still limp along on XP.  You just haven't found the DLL yet that causes this error.  Depends can also show you the troublemaker, you must use its Profile command.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was wrong, didn't pay enough attention at first. My main .exe module imports `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` (and no other modules). I build it with 2013_xp toolset, platform is set to Windows in the linker options, minimum required version - 5.01. What am I missing? My code does not directly use this function, if I build with 2010 toolset it will run on XP with no code modifications whatsoever.

Comment: Use the linker's /VERBOSE option to narrow down which .obj file uses it.  Linking an old copy of libcmt.lib can cause this.  Some game engines get this wrong.

Comment: @RhysCausey: I did, it was a pretty silly problem. Turned out my code did, in fact, use `InitializeCriticalSectionEx`. Or, rather, one of the 3rd-party libraries did. Don't forget that after switching to `120_xp` toolset you have to go to linker options and set subsystem to /WINDOWS, because it's not done by default.

Comment: @HansPassant Compilers, even MS' ones, aren't always diligent in what subsystem version they put into the executable (and it can be overridden with a linker option anyway). So, it's quite possible that a Vista+ API is used while subsystem is set to 5.01 or even lower.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009896/vs2013-compilation-for-winxp-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located says that a dependent dynamic library can cause this. Turns out, quite logically, that it's also true for dependent static libraries.

Comment: Voting to reopen because this is a nontrivial and recurring problem.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I think the question was closed for a reason, it's too specific. It was an interesting experience as far as searching for the culprit module that depends on a forbidden function, and there is some great advice in the comments, but still. Besides, Win XP is finally no longer supported even by MS themselves. I say stop beating the dead horse.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe whether XP is a "dead horse" or not has no bearing on the validity of the question. You wouldn't close a question about Linux 2.4 or 2.6, would you? The question applies not just to `v120_xp` but to any other `_xp` toolset (which even VS2017 has), and `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` is one of the few signature functions that surface whenever a program was compiled without XP support.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe the answer as I see it is: "it's not enough for your program to be compiled with the v120_xp toolset. Any 3rd-party libraries that you link against -- both static and dynamic -- must be compiled with XP support as well. That because API control with the WINVER macro is only done at compiler, not linker, level (etc.)"